# How to propagate error in httpProvider responseError interceptor

Tags: angularjs

We have the following code in place for form validation:

```
            $scope.masterModel.$save().then(function (data) {
                $scope.masters.data.push(data);
                $location.path('/master/edit/' + data.id);
            }).error(function (data) {
                $scope.errors = data.data;
            });
```

Now we added code to generally catch code 500 server errors on a global level to the app.js

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($injector) {

        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                // do something on error
                if (rejection.status === 500) {
                    var angularModalService= $injector.get("ModalService");
                    angularModalService.showModal({
                        templateUrl: "templates/common/session.html",
                        controller: "ModalController"
                    }).then(function (modal) {
                        modal.element.modal();
                        modal.close.then(function (result) {
                            if (result) {

                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    });
}]);
```

As soon as we add this code, the error callback in the first code does not work anymore.

I think we have to somehow propagate the error in the responseError callback, but how does that work?

AngularJS Version is 1.5.11

Comment: See my answer, it is pretty simple actually. You just need to add a line to your interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "reject the rejection" in the interceptor  and return it in order for the error to be propagated:P

```js
 var app=   angular.module('MyApp', []);
 
 app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http, $q) {
           
  $http.get("http://www.example.invalid/fake.json")
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("success");
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("controller error handler");
    });
});


app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($injector, $q) {

        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                console.log("interceptor error handler");
            
                // do something on error
                if (rejection.status === 500) {
                  // do something...                  
                }
                
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I added the line

```
 return $q.reject(rejection);
```

at the end of your interceptor. You can check the console and see that now both messages are logged.